# Problem with getting the locator of a dropdown in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, relative-locators

Please take a look at the page @ https://www.kayak.co.in/stays. When I type a location say New Delhi in the Location textbox a dropdown appears indicating the list of options to be selected. However when I try to identify that element using the Dev Tools by clicking it, it disappears and a I am not able to obtain the locator. I tried passing the locator along with Key Action Enter: i.e.  SendKeys(locator + Keys.Enter) as per the UI behavior but even it fails to work which is blocking my script. Please let me know how to proceed.

[image]

As mentioned I am not able to get the dropdown locator and Keys.Enter doesn't even work

Comment: Try this, dropdown, instead click on dev tools, use the search on dev tools with some text on html results

Comment: But I am not able to locate that dropdown in the DOM as typing in Dev Tools makes the element disappear...Can someone let me know the XPath of the dropdown?

Comment: You are right, i saw it at botton of HTML, try this XPATH "//div[contains(@class, 'ui-dialog-Popover')]" but cant see childrens of that element

Answer (score 0):

This is the full XPath. Feel free to remove useless parts.

```
//body[@id='k4-r'][@class='keel kl kl-override HotelsSearch react react-st wide a11y-focus-outlines wide-fd en_IN horizon'][@style='display: block;']/div[@id='RaKq'][@class='Common-Page-StandardPage Base-Search-LandingPage Base-Search-SearchPage Hotels-Search-HotelSearchPage cur_inr vm-fd dual-view']/div[@id='e6vK'][@class='Common-Layout-StandardBody withFooter']/main[@id='e6vK-pageContent'][@class='pageContent withDrawer moved wide ']/div[@id='RaKq-fd'][@class='SearchPage__FrontDoor']/div[@id='dbfN'][@class='Base-Frontdoor-FrontDoor Hotels-Frontdoor-HotelFrontDoor']/div[@id='VQMg'][@class='Common-Frontdoor-HarmonizedFrontDoorContent']/div[@class='coverPhotoContainer splash'][@data-search-form-container]/div[@id='x0Lx'][@class='_kkL _jcQ _ia2']/div[@id='dbfN-primary'][@class='primary-content']/section/div[@class='keel-container s-t-bp']/div[@class='form-section'][@id='main-search-form']/div[@class='form-container']/div[@id='c2Y_4'][@class='Ui-Searchforms-Hotels-Components-HotelSearchForm-container ']/div[@class='HPw7 HPw7-pres-default HPw7-pres-responsive HPw7-pres-dark HPw7-pres-rooms-guests HPw7-pres-wide-dates']/div[@class='HPw7-form-fields-and-submit']/div[@class='HPw7-form-fields']/div[@class='HPw7-destination']/div[@class='BCcW']/div[@class='k_my k_my-mod-theme-mcfly-search k_my-mod-radius-base k_my-mod-size-large k_my-mod-font-size-base k_my-mod-spacing-default k_my-mod-text-overflow-ellipsis k_my-mod-state-default']/input[@type='text'][@value][@class='k_my-input'][@tabindex='0'][@placeholder='Enter a city, hotel, airport, address or landmark'][@aria-autocomplete='list'][@aria-haspopup='listbox']
```

Generated by https://github.com/sputnick-dev/retrieveCssOrXpathSelectorFromTextOrNode

Simplified:

```
//input[@type='text'][@value][@placeholder='Enter a city, hotel, airport, address or landmark'][@aria-haspopup='listbox']
```

Or after typed `new delhi`:

```
//input[@type='text'][@value='Near Indira Gandhi Airport New Delhi India, New Delhi, National Capital Territory of India, India'][@class='k_my-input'][@tabindex='0'][@placeholder='Enter a city, hotel, airport, address or landmark'][@aria-autocomplete='list'][@aria-haspopup='listbox'][@aria-activedescendant='1070140428_hotel_Near Indira Gandhi Airport New Delhi India, New Delhi, National Capital Territory of India, India']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full SeleniumBase script (https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) that will do all that for you. `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the script with `python` or `pytest`. The sleeps are only there so that you can see what's happening. Otherwise it runs very fast!

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__])

class KayakTest(BaseCase):
    def test_kayak_search(self):
        self.open("https://www.kayak.co.in/stays")
        self.type(
            'input[placeholder*="Enter a city"]',
            "New Delhi, National Capital Territory of India"
        )
        self.sleep(1)
        self.add_text('input[placeholder*="Enter a city"]', "\n")
        self.sleep(1)
        self.click("div.ATGJ-monthWrapper div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(23)")
        self.sleep(1)
        self.click("div.ATGJ-monthWrapper div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(27)")
        self.sleep(1)
        self.click("svg.c8LPF-icon")
        self.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I am currently using Selenium and C# as the script development environment. Any solutions for that?